# Ionic/react HTML audio stops playing after backgrounding the app for some minutes

Tags: ionic-framework, html5-audio, capacitor, ionic-native, background-mode

We have an app heavily focused on streaming audio files using the HTML
audio tag player. In some Android devices the stream will stop after about 3 minutes after the user has minimized/backgrounded the app. Then they will have to foreground the app again and pause-play the track to continue. Sometimes it loses the stream completely when you foreground the app. On other devices it continues playing nornally. I've already tried using the `cordova-plugin-background-mode` and I enable it on app initialization but seems to be not working. Will I be forced to use native audio player to solve this?

```
ionic info:
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 6.17.1 (/home/nikosx/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 5.6.9

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI : 3.3.3
@capacitor/android : 3.3.3
@capacitor/core : 3.3.3
@capacitor/ios : 3.3.3

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
native-run : 1.5.0

System:

NodeJS : v14.18.1 (/usr/bin/node)
npm : 6.14.15
OS : Linux 5.13
```

Comment: Can you investigate and find out why its only "3 minutes" See if possible to increase buffer size so that the app can stream longer

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to a lot of devices. The devices I have in my disposal work fine. iOS works perfectly. In some test devices the audio works fine if we disable power saving features (eg Samsung's One UI). Will test the buffer size on the first opportunity.